# Getting an error while trying to install robotframework-appiumlibrary

Tags: python-2.7, appium, robotframework

Mac OS - 10.15.7
Python - 2.7.18

I used the command to install "pip install robotframework-appiumlibrary" and following is the error i get.

```
@Amiths-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip install robotframework-appiumlibrary
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting robotframework-appiumlibrary
  Using cached robotframework_appiumlibrary-1.5.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting docutils>=0.8.1
  Using cached docutils-0.17.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (575 kB)
Collecting six>=1.10.0
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting decorator>=3.3.2
  Using cached decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting kitchen>=1.2.4
  Using cached kitchen-1.2.6.tar.gz (255 kB)
Collecting selenium>=2.47.1
  Using cached selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (904 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: robotframework>=2.6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from robotframework-appiumlibrary) (4.0.1)
Collecting Appium-Python-Client>=0.28
  Using cached Appium-Python-Client-1.1.0.tar.gz (53 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xn/c052lddx4qz1lm8h6thg0w_h0000gn/T/pip-install-IQfrSA/appium-python-client/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xn/c052lddx4qz1lm8h6thg0w_h0000gn/T/pip-install-IQfrSA/appium-python-client/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/xn/c052lddx4qz1lm8h6thg0w_h0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-AVKVXp
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xn/c052lddx4qz1lm8h6thg0w_h0000gn/T/pip-install-IQfrSA/appium-python-client/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/xn/c052lddx4qz1lm8h6thg0w_h0000gn/T/pip-install-IQfrSA/appium-python-client/setup.py", line 19, in <module>
        from appium.common.helper import library_version
      File "appium/common/helper.py", line 20
        def extract_const_attributes(cls: type) -> Dict[str, Any]:
                                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

@Amiths-MacBook-Pro ~ % python setup.py egg_info                
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to use python 3.x

Comment: @BryanOakley But as per Appium, it's full supported in 2.7. Following the info from their page.
"It is fully supported under Python 2.7. Python 3.6+ support is still experimental"
[Link] https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary

Comment: @Amith while robotframework-apiumlibrary might not use any python3 features, underlying appium is not. I even filed a bug report against it but maintainer just closed it: https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary/issues/300

Comment: eg. you cannot run appium on python that does not support type hints, probably 3.5 - no matter what the author says :D

Comment: "underlying appium is not" should be just "underlying appium is"

Comment: @rasjani Thank you.. I changed the python to 3.7.7 and i was able to install without any errors